# com.google.inject.Key cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android

While compiling an Android project, I get this error:

> The type com.google.inject.Key cannot be resolved. It is indirectly
>   referenced from required .class files

It suggests "ConfigureBuildPath" as a possible solution, but I'm unsure of what that means and how to do that.  How do I debug and fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that you do not have everything on the classpath that is required to build the project.  You need to add the jar containing `com.google.inject.Key` to the build path.

Comment: how i can add this jar ?